# Question about $n$ random points in a regular polygon, and a limiting probability

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, limits-and-convergence, polygons

Suppose we choose $n$ uniformly random points in a disk, then draw the smallest circle that encloses all of those points. There is [evidence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4799757/398708) suggesting that the probability that the enclosing circle is completely in the disk, approaches $1/2$ as $n\to\infty$.

If we replace the disk and circle with regular $p$-gons, does this (alleged) result still hold? That is,

> In a regular $p$-gon, choose $n$ uniformly random points. Then draw the smallest regular $p$-gon that encloses all those points. Do we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\{\text{Probability the enclosing $p$-gon is completely in the outer $p$-gon}\}=\frac12$ for all $p\ge3$?

There may be more than one way to draw the smallest enclosing $p$-gon. If possible, draw it so that it is completely in the outer $p$-gon.

To choose random points in the (outer) $p$-gon, we can draw a square around the $p$-gon, then choose random points in the square, and ignore those points that fall outside the $p$-gon.

### Squares

I considered squares, with $n=2$.

Assume the outer square is in the complex plane, with vertices $0, 1, i, 1+i$.

Let the two random points be $u_1=a+bi$ and $u_2=c+di$, where $a,b,c,d$ are independent uniformly random real numbers in $[0,1]$.

The enclosing square will have vertices $u_1,u_2,u_1+\frac12(u_2-u_1)(1+i),u_1+\frac12(u_2-u_1)(1-i)$.

If the enclosing square is completely in the outer square, then the last two vertices must be in the outer square, yielding the following system of inequalities:

$0<a+b+c-d<2$
$0<a+b-c+d<2$
$0<a-b+c+d<2$
$0<-a+b+c+d<2$

I do not know how to calculate the probability that these inequalities are all satisfied. But I ran a simulation on Excel, and the probability seems to be $2/3$, which is the same probability as the [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4799757/398708) with $n=2$. Is that a coincidence, or is there an underlying principle?

### Equilateral triangles

I ran a similar simulation for equilateral triangles with $n=2$.

For each pair of random points, there are two ways to draw the smallest enclosing triangle (they are reflections across the line segment joining the two random points). As I explained above, if possible, we draw the enclosing triangle so that it is completely in the outer triangle. My simulation suggests that the probability that the enclosing triangle is completely in the outer polygon, is $3/4$.

But if, instead, we choose between the two possible enclosing triangles at random, then the probability seems to be $1/2$. Note that $2/3$ (the probability with the circle and square) is between $3/4$ and $1/2$.

As $n\to\infty$, there will be less freedom in drawing the enclosing triangle, and I conjecture that the probability will approach $1/2$, just like the circle.